# React - How to get subtotal of mapped items after filtering them?

Tags: reactjs, filter, reduce, array.prototype.map, subtotal

I am trying to get subtotal of items after filtering them:

```
const total = (allItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)).toFixed(2);
```

This is the filter:

```
{allItems
  .filter((items) => {
    if(items.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)){
      return items
      } 
   })
   .map((item, i) => {
        return(
        <div className='item' key={Math.random()} id={Math.random()}> 
          <div className='text'>{i+1}. {item.name} </div>
          <div className='number'> {(Math.round(item.price * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)} </div>
        </div>
      )})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could isolate your filter function in a const and then do the operation on it:

```
const filteredItems = allItems
  .filter((items) => {
    if(items.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)){
      return items
      } 
   })

const filteredTotal = filteredItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)).toFixed(2)
```

and then in your render:

```
{filteredItems.
   .map((item, i) => {
        return(
        <div className='item' key={Math.random()} id={Math.random()}> 
          <div className='text'>{i+1}. {item.name} </div>
          <div className='number'> {(Math.round(item.price * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)} </div>
        </div>
      )})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call .length on the resulting array.

```
allItems.filter(filterFunction).length
```

Or if you want to do it directly in the map function you can get the array from the third argument

```
myFilteredArray.map(value, index, myArray) => (
  <div>{myArray.length}</div>
)
```

Comment: Question asked about "total" so it may be worth discussing how to reduce to sum over an array.